# Conditional probability density function of X given Y = y

Tags: probability

$f_{x\mid y} (x\mid y) = {(3(x^2+y^2))\over(3y^2+1)}, 0 < x < 1, 0 < y < 1$

looking to find $\mathsf P(1/4 < X < 1/2\mid Y = 3/4)$

not exactly sure what to make of this. Would this look  something like

$\begin{align}
p_{X|Y=3/4} (1/4 < X <1/2) 
& = \mathsf P(1/4 < X <1/2 \mid Y = 3/4)
\\
& = p_{X,Y}(1/4 < X <1/2)/p_Y(3/4)
\end{align}$
 ? then plug in the function for x?

Comment: Please use LaTeX to typeset :)

Comment: @gt6989b I am not sure how to do this, but I will try to figure out how to do so and correct

Comment: Set $y=3/4$ in your expression for $f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)$ to obtain a function of $x$ alone. This is the _conditional_ density of $X$ when $Y$ happens to have value $3/4$: it does not have $y$ mentioned anywhere in its formula. Then, use this conditional density to compute the (conditional) probability that $X \in (0.25,0.5)$.

Answer (score 1):

You are given a conditional density function: $$f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y) = \dfrac{3(x^2+y^2)}{3y^2+1}\text{ when }(x,y)\in(0;1)^2$$

You wish to find the conditional probability: $$\mathsf P(\tfrac 1 4 < X< \tfrac 12 \mid Y=\tfrac 3 4)$$

This is simply an integration over the requisite interval: $$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(\tfrac 1 4 < X< \tfrac 1 2 \mid Y=\tfrac 3 4)
& = \int_{1/4}^{1/2} f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid 3/4) \operatorname d x
\\ & = \int_{1/4}^{1/2} \dfrac{3(x^2+(3/4)^2)}{3(3/4)^2+1}\operatorname d x
\end{align}$$

Now just simplify and complete.

That is all.